# Unknown 405 error on C# code + Fine tuning

Tags: c#, httprequest, webclient

I started learning C# recently, and found a practical application that isn't too difficult to accomplish, but I need some help figuring out my link I'm pretty sure. Let me show you.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
   ... Namespace class etc etc     
Console.WriteLine("Trying...");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var nameValue = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        nameValue.Add("FIRST NAME", "myname");
        nameValue.Add("LAST NAME", "mylname");
        nameValue.Add("GRADE", "mygrade");
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScB206NtDOPl4_lQfCk9SZwqKfVRARVm0dSLujSj4qkWulp3Q/viewform");
        byte[] response = client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", nameValue);
        string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

The linked form is one I created to model my schools. It's an attendance form (HS senior!) and I'm just trying to get it from my email and auto fill it every morning (lol), but I'm focused on this section first. My code generates a 405:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadBits(WebRequest request, Stream readStream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 chunkSize, Byte[] header, Byte[] footer)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
   at AttendanceAutomaticac.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Lee\source\repos\AttendanceAutomaticac\Program.cs:line 18
```

Edit: Can I use any apis for this that someone knows of?

Bad link probably, but it works? I found this code via a link to google on a forum, and modified it slightly to fit my form. I'm also not quite sure whether or not the 3rd value will work for a single choice answer... So, I just need any other solution / explanation, I'm not too great at debugging and problem solving errors beyond StackOverflow in C# yet as I have minimal experience with it.

Comment: I highly doubt a URL like `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScB206NtDOPl4_lQfCk9SZwqKfVRARVm0dSLujSj4qkWulp3Q/viewform` would allow you to perform a POST to it. Thus the 405. You probably need to find a different URL to post your form to.

Comment: @mason Makes sense, I had a suspicion it may have been something related to Google not allowing it... Still, its the exact format the sample code originally said to use. Maybe they changed?